# How do I fix the XMLHttpRequest cannot load on noodlio-pay on Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

This is the Error i'm Getting? I have looked around almost everywhere.. I don't understand and I'm very new to this.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://noodlio-pay.p.mashape.com/tokens/create. A wildcard '*' cannot
>   be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the
>   credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8102' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>
> controllers.js:3763 null

Comment: The error seems crystal clear, the headers are wrong, you can't use credentials and at the same time allow everyone access.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean by ''you can't use credentials and at the same time allow everyone access.''? I'm very new new to this. i would be so greatful if you could help.Thanks

Comment: The server you're trying to contact with your ajax request sends out the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, which means you're using credentials. At the same time, that same server is sending out the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which means any origin is allowed access to that server, without applying the same-origin policy. You can't have both, there's no point in using credentials, if anyone can access.

Comment: if put the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false or remove it works fine for that controller but everything else doesn't work

Comment: i get a new error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/app/index.php/json/getAllMenuType?pageno=1&maxrow=15. Request header field X-Mashape-Key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

Comment: what do I need to put for both to work?

Comment: I'm guessing that's a custom header for Mashape, and it seems it's not allowed. I don't know Mashape, so I guess you'd have to check their documentation ?

Comment: https://market.mashape.com/noodlio/noodlio-pay-smooth-payments-with-stripe#

Comment: I feel very frustrated 2 days nothing done,

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [Enable cros on ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/). and check allow cros on server side also

Comment: i think you have't enabled CROS on server side..check it

Comment: how do i enable CROS on server side?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I managed to fix it but some progress and this is how I did it and it seems to work for now:

In my app.js --> .config I removed

`$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

and replaced it

`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8102/', true);
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.send(null);`

and then worked but then when these headers where called in the controller it crashed again.

`// add the following headers for authentication
  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Mashape-Key']  = NOODLIO_PAY_API_KEY;
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']   = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Accept']         = 'application/json';`

So I decided to Add these header in the function and just call them when the button is clicked.

just like this

$scope.headerscheck = function(){

// add the following headers for authentication
  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Mashape-Key']  = NOODLIO_PAY_API_KEY;
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']   = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Accept']         = 'application/json';

}

but now I don't know how to kill the scope function after use without doing a refresh.